# How to get row-wise absolute minimum value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe for example

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 2 | -3 |

I want to pick the minimum absolute value: `table2`

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 2 | -3 | -1 |

For now I am using `df.abs().idxmin(axis="columns")` and I get: `table3`

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | 2 | -3 | Col1 |

I would like to ask how can I convert table 3 to table 2?

Comment: are the values in table 1 and table 2 supposed to be different?

Comment: I updated, table 1 and 2 should be the same thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) (numpy counterpart of [`DataFrame.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html)). Since you want to extract the original values, it's more convenient to access those values at the numpy level.

I added an extra row to your MRE for demonstration:

```
cols = np.argmin(df.abs().to_numpy(), axis=1) # [0, 2]
rows = range(len(cols))                       # [0, 1]
df['Result'] = df.to_numpy()[rows, cols]

#    Col1  Col2  Col3  Result
# 0    -1     2    -3      -1
# 1    10    -5     4       4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [*`df.abs().min(axis=1)`*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> data = {'col1': [1], 'col2': [2], 'col3': [-3]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2    -3
>>> df['Result'] = df.abs().min(axis=1)
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3  Result
0     1     2    -3       1
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I would like to ask how can I get the non absolute value, after I did the compare by the absolute value? I have updated my example to make it more clear.
Thanks